# Report Viewer tool running on the local and do not work on browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on visual studio 2012 asp.net c#  and I am using the Report Viewer control to display my reports.

It'S Working in the local excellently but they do not work on browsers not get error.
I tried using Report Versions 10,11 and 12 and i experienced the same problem regardless.
Please find in the code defined in the attached file config
It also Upload the libraries to a folder Bin

```html
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering = "false" ShowParameterPrompts="True" Width="770px" >
                            </rsweb:ReportViewer>



 <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <assemblies>

        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </assemblies>

    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </buildProviders>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: You need to add `AJAX ScriptManager` control along with reportviewer control.

Comment: i am failing to understand what problem you are having. Are you able to view reports on your local IIS server, but when you upload your project to a remote server you cannt view your reports any more.

Comment: Yes I can not view the reports on the remote server when upload the project.

Comment: I'am use tool ajax control It could be the problem

Comment: The problem is still not resolved!
Do any of you have a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the ReportViewer dlls to the bin directory on the remote server. 
So for example when i upload my project to GoDaddy i upload the following dlls to the bin directory:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
```

Comment: I have already upload libraries
But I want to make sure their tracks. C:\Windows.old\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  C:\Windows.old\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

Comment: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll From C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in

Comment: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll From C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\ReportViewer

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll From C:\Windows.old\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

Comment: Thank you very much on the speed of your response and follow you to my problem.

Comment: The problem is still not resolved! Do any of you have a solution to this problem